# How to compare a system date with the date from MySQL database in php

Tags: php, mysql, date

I want to compare my system date from the date from MySQL database and the comparison should be like if the system date has the diffrence of 10 days than the date from my table's date.

For e.g. my sytem date: 2013-7-31 and the table's date is 2013-8-10 it should echo a msg "10 days left for renewal."

I know how to add days into a date in php but I have no idea of how should I compare these two.

```
$mydt = date("Y-m-d");
$alertday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($mydt. " + 10 days"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just convert the db table time to a normal unix timestamp subtract and divide by number seconds in a day

```
$now = time();
$dbtime = strtotime($tabledate);

$daysleft = ($now-$dbtime) / ( 60*60*24);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `date_diff()`-> `DateTime::diff`

```
$interval  = date_diff($date1, $date2); //$date1, $date2 are DateTime objects.
echo $interval->d; //Outputs number of day difference.
```

More functionality can be found here:

http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.dateinterval.php

http://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.diff.php

Comment: @user2274075 it's working. You have to create DateTime objects (`$date1 and $date2` first). If something doesn't work you'll need to explain what doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

in your query let say you pass in the value from `$now = strttotime("now");`
you can then do the following in MySQL

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT($now "%Y-%m-%d") = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(DATE_FIELD,INTERVAL -10 DAY), "%Y-%m-%d")
```